# Print a pdf file at client side

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, pdf

i want to issue the print command to a Pdf file without using adobe Pdf viewer's print button.instead of using print button in Pdf viewer i want do it using separate event, is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

### HTML

```
<input type="submit"  value="Print" name="Submit" id="printbtn" onclick="printPDF('D:/asb.Pdf')" />
```

### Javascript

```
function printPDF(htmlPage)
{ 
var w = window.open("about:blank");
w.document.write(htmlPage);
if (navigator.appName == 'Microsoft Internet Explorer') window.print();
else w.print();
}
```

Comment: how can i give the path to the pdf on the server? i am creating the pdf in the root of web application

Comment: @TAB give Relative Paths like 
-**index.pdf**
-**/graphics/image.pdf**
-**/help/articles/how-do-i-set-up-a-webpage.pdf**

Answer (score 0):

Yes It's Possible. But You cannot do this with javascript or JQuery. you need to have javascript library to do this. Please check out this links.

- [JSPDF](https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF)
- [Mozilla PDF.js](http://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/)

Hope This Will Helps.